# regex match hastag, mention, url and special characters from data tweet

Tags: javascript, regex, twitter, match

Example data from tweet:

I always meet @gEmbul at #kampus we always open the site https://www.youtube.com/ facebook# :) @007

the date is string, i want match mention with symbol @, hastag with symbol #, any url, and special caracter.

I will match hastag # in front of hastag and behind hastag

this my code

```js
var data = "I always meet @gEmbul at #kampus we always open the site https://www.youtube.com/ facebook# :) @007"
function clean(data) {
 data = data.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, '')
      .replace(/\B\@\w\w+\b/g, '')
      .replace(/\B\#\w\w+\b/g, '');
 return data;
}
console.log(clean(data))
```

i will return

i always meet at we always open site

thanks.

Comment: Try `replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+|\B[@#]\w+\b|\b\w+[@#]\B/g, '')` or `.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+|\B[@#]\w+\b|\b\w+[@#]\B|\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B/g, '')` - see https://jsfiddle.net/48hmrse2/

Comment: oke thanks you very much

Comment: Does it work as expected? I am not sure about the smiley `\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B` part.

Comment: i want try with other text

Comment: i have try with other text this is solve, can you write on commend So i can solve this problem

Comment: I think you will have to check `\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B` part and adjust as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sugges shrinking the pattern a bit (the 2 regexes you have differ in just 1 char and that can be done with a `[#@]`  character class, and since you remove the matches, you may just combine the regexps with a `|` alternation operator):

```js
var data = "I always meet @gEmbul at #kampus we always open the site https://www.youtube.com/ facebook# :) @007"
function clean(data) {
 data = data.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+|\B[@#]\w+\b|\b\w+[@#]\B|\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B/g, '');
 return data;
}
document.body.innerHTML = clean(data);
```

**Details**:

- `(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+` - a regex that matches an URL that may span across newlines
- `|` - or
- `\B[@#]\w+\b` - a `@` or `#` followed with 1+ word chars (as a whole word)
- `|` - or
- `\b\w+[@#]\B` - 1+ word chars followed with `@` or `#` (as a whole word)
- `|` - or
- `\B[^\w\s]{2,}\B` - a non-word boundary, 2 or more chars other than word and whitespace, and again a non-word boundary. Remove `\B` to match 2 or more non-whitespace/non-word chars in any context.